# Is the delta-pack updated by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, updates, delta-pack

I have a doubt. I've been using Eclipse Indigo RCs and eventually installed an RC3 Delta-pack to match the release i was using.

After the latest updates, i believe I'm up-to-date with the Final Indigo release, but what about the Delta-pack? I don't detect any problems, but i wonder if Eclipse Update manages the Delta-pack update...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not... as the delta pack is not feature based, but *just* a number of plug-ins packaged in a zip or tar file...

Comment: So i believe it was a coincidence that between Indigo Release Candidates there were no changes on the delta-pack... :-\ Thanks.